# Combination of getter and list modification in Java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, getter

today i dealt with a Java problem that really confused me.
I have the following code:

```
List<ObjectXY> someList = obj.getListOfObjectsXY(); // getter returns 2 elements
someList.add(new ObjectXY());

obj.getListOfObjectsXY(); // getter now returns 3 elements
```

When i add an element to a list, the getter gets some kind of overwritten. Is this because `someList` acts like a reference on the result of the getter in this case? Or what else causes this effect?

I solved the problem with the following code by using another list:

```
List<ObjectXY> someList = obj.getListOfObjectsXY(); // result: 2 elements

List<ObjectXY> someOtherList = new ArrayList<ObjectXY>();
someOtherList.addAll(someList);
someOtherList.add(new ObjectXY());

obj.getListOfObjectsXY(); // result: 2 elements
```

But i am still some kind of confused because i didn't expect Java to behave this way.
Can anyone explain to me what i did wrong and why it is so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because in Java, references are pass-by-value, and `obj.getListOfObjectsXY()` returns the original list object, which is being modified by your `add` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The returned result is indeed just a copy of a reference to the same object as you are using internally. Counting on the caller to not modify the object is error-prone.

One solution is to return a reference to an unmodifiable list wrapping your list. See `Collections.unmodifiableList()`. The getter caller will be unable to modify your list.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this because someList acts like a reference on the result of the
>   getter in this case?

Yes. The list you received was just a reference to the same, original list you had. Any changes made on this variable would be reflected on the original list.

By adding the list's values to a new list you explicitly constructed a new object and thus they are separated.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `obj.getListOfObjectsXY()` everytime return you the same object and in Java object references are pass-by-value. So, when you do a `someList.add(new ObjectXY());`, it's actually setting the property of the object someList which is poiting to `obj.getListOfObjectsXY()`.

And in the latter case, you are just copying someList to someOtherList. Then you added one more element to the same someOtherList but not to the someList. So, you getting 2 elements in 
obj.getListOfObjectsXY(); is perfectly valid.