# Modification of a private class attribute only with getter

Tags: java, getter

I read this article: [Combination of getter and list modification in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290370/combination-of-getter-and-list-modification-in-java)

and now I wonder if a modification on all types of class attributes is possible only by access via a getter.
I tried with an Integer object

```
public class SomeClass
{
     private Integer someInteger = 9;
     public Integer getSomeInteger()
     {
         return someInteger;                          // id = 18, value =  9
     }
}
```

Now I try to modify someInteger in another Class:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
Integer someInteger = someClass.getSomeInteger();     // id = 18, value =  9
someInteger += 1;                                     // id = 26, value = 10
Integer anotherInteger = someClass.getSomeInteger();  // id = 18, value =  9
```

With a debugger I inspect the object id. In my calling class someInteger first has the same ID as in the getter. After adding a 1, someInteger get a new id and the original class attribute is not edited.

Okay my try with adding a number failed, but is there a possibility to modify the originally object?

I asked me about the difference between the linked example with a List and my example with an Integer. 
My idea is, that

```
someInteger += 1;
```

internally creates a new Integer object. In contrast the list has its own modification methods, which not causes the instantiation of a new List object. Is this right?
From this it would follow that all data types with self modifying methods that I can access by a getter have to be protected from modifying by other classes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value should answer your question. Your local `Integer someInteger` is not the same reference as the one in the class. Modifying your's does not touch the other. And since `Integer` is immutable, you'll create a new object by doing "+1" (should be equivalent to `someInteger = Integer.valueOf(someInteger.intValue() + 1)` due to auto boxing / unboxing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not implementing a proper setter, and `Integer` is immutable.

So what you are doing when incrementing `someInteger` right now is incrementing the value of reference `someInteger` scoped to the method where you are executing the increment, without impacting on the private field.

A setter method takes an argument, and **internally** sets the field's value, after validation if applicable.

So your setter should look like:

```
public void setSomeInteger(int value) {
    // TODO validate if applicable
    someInteger = value;
}
```

Then you would invoke it as:

```
someClassInstance.setSomeInteger(42);
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Please read the linked article. I'm afraid of modifying class attributes only with a getter.

Comment: @Karina if your getter returns mutable objects (such as a `List`), it is possible to modify it by invoking the getter. This is not possible for `Integer`.